# Icon background color in Android 12 Splash Screen does not work

Tags: android, android-splashscreen

In my Android project I use [Splash Screen API](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen) to add splash screen to my app. My theme that I apply to application in Manifest looks like this:

```
<style name="Launcher" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/background</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenIconBackgroundColor">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/AppTheme</item>
</style>
```

`@color/orange` in `windowSplashScreenIconBackgroundColor` should add circle shaped backround around icon. However, background is not added, there is just an icon and a background.

I add corresponding theme to my app as following:

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name_label"
    android:theme="@style/Launcher">
```

I tried to change splash screen `windowSplashScreenBackground` to `orange` and it worked, so the problem is not that my theme is ignore somehow.

Comment: facing the same issue. Did you manage to solve the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to override `windowSplashScreenIconBackgroundColor`, you have to extend `Theme.SplashScreen.IconBackground` theme, not the `Theme.SplashScreen`. Something like this:

```
<style name="Launcher" parent="Theme.SplashScreen.IconBackground">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/background</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenIconBackgroundColor">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/AppTheme</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

[As shown on the Splash Screen Api](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen#set-theme), Make sure you prepend the item name with `android:`

For example, replace:

```xml
<item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/background</item>
```

with:

```xml
<item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/background</item>
```

This is what I have:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!--Splash Screen api: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen#set-theme-->
    <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.NoActionBar">
        <!--fill the background with a specific single color-->
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/dark</item>
        <!--background behind the splash screen icon  TODO this is not working -->
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenIconBackgroundColor">@color/dark</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Prepending `android:` requires API level 31 while my current min is lower and I want to have icon background on all available API levels.

Comment: omg, this  has nothing to do with the question. you should not use `android:`, you should use `app:` (or basically not using any prefix) for backward computability of older versions of Android